# Method not executing?

Tags: java, android, xml, service, timer

I am running a 20 second timer in the background of my app using a service. I want the service to call my GameOver class when it is done with it's timer. By the way, the user is constantly switching activities while the timer is running, but when it finishes, the user has to be taken to the game over screen no matter what. I have put a toast in the service, but that doesn't show up.

Here is my service:

[image]

Here is my Main Menu where I call the service:

[image]

Here is the manifest where I show the service:

[image]

Please let me know as to why the service or the timer aren't running. Thank you so much for all of your help, I really appreciate it! If you need any more code, just let me know and I will show you. Thanks!

:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours on this issue, I figured out my pathetic error:

I had the service declaration OUTSIDE of the '< application>' end tag.

**facepalm**

ALWAYS keep service declarations inside of  tag

Answer (score 0):

Your toast is not showing because a Service can't directly manipulate the UI, such as showing toasts.

To do this from a service, you need to run the Toast code on the main thread. This can be done as such:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(TwentySeconds.this.getApplicationContext(), "Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Your CountDownTimer isn't working because you never start it. Very simple.
You create the CountDownTimer, but never call .start() on the object.

```
cdt.start();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. For some reason, the GameOver activity still isn't being called after 20 seconds. Please let me know why. Thanks!

Comment: Even after putting in cdt.start()

Comment: Does the countdown timer stop at all? In your screenshot it seems to be set to run for 30 sec? :)